# Production ASP.net App slower than Development

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework

I have a asp .net webApplication with Entity Framework that is running considerably slower in the production server.

I'm testing in the localhost against a local SQLServer database and in the production server the application uses a local database as well.

So I was expecting the times to be similar, if not faster in production.

The server is a new machine with more RAM and a faster processor than my machine.

I found that improving code helped me tremendously (things like stringBuilder replacing lots of concats), but what I can't understand is the difference in times!

I Compared times in always in Release mode. Using simple Visual Studio publish.

Where should I start?

IIS in production?
SQL Server?
Can it be the connection string?
Keep investigating the code?

Thanks in advance,

Diogo

Comment: How are you comparing times exactly?  We need more information.

Comment: Writing to file using log4net (saving the time with StopWatch).
Methods accessing the database are slower but methods that are just plain processing with no database access are also slower

Comment: yeah what the eff. I can run in visual studio localhost blazing fast, then in IIS it's such a slow DB connection that it chokes on big view models and is unusable.

Answer (score 3):

I would start with breaking down the issue. For example sql server times and iis times. You can separate different parts of code and measure execution times, etc.

[SQL Server Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091.aspx) is good tool to start with and for ASP.NET You can start with simple [trace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386420.aspx) and [page tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/94c55d08.aspx).

Some more info about [testing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb924375.aspx) and [performance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649152.aspx)

You should have same data in production and development machines to expect same results. Also production server can be busy with other things that You may not have on development machine.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using [Glympse](http://getglimpse.com/) to get more detailed information on what is going on in production.

Another thing to look at would be the [Server vs. Workstation garbage collector](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/UsingTheServerRatherThanWorkstationGarbageCollectorWithTheNETFrameworkCLR.aspx). That is definitely one difference between running a site on your dev machine vs. deploying it to a server.

There have been some situations that the [Server GC has caused performance issues in the past](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/911716).

Answer (score 1):

For me, it turned out to be the system.codedom that caused the slow performance in the production environment while everything was working fine in IIS Express locally while debugging.

Check your Web.config and remove the following.

```
 <system.codedom>
<compilers>
  <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
  <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
</compilers></system.codedom>
```

These can be safely removed from the web.config if you do pre-compilation and only use the compiled assemblies on the webserver.

Answer (score 0):

Try Perfview http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28567, ETL-based, specially designed for analyzing managed code performance.